# DHCP server not working in new version of ubuntu with ethernet name as enp9s0?

Tags: networking, dhcp

Why does new version of ubuntu  shows different ethernet names like enp9s0 and wireless as enp9s0 instead of eth0 or wlan0. Is there any problem with the device. When i tried setting up DHCP server, then in virtual box with same ethernet name as eth0, dhcp ran on that server but virtual machine with ethernet name as enp9s0, dhcp server did not worked. I have properly configured all the interfaces in /etc/network/interface. I have also properly configured /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf. I have also set up interfaces in /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server to work on INTERFACES="enp9s0". But it still does not work why ?

Answer (score 0):

To answer half answer your question, Ubuntu creates a random (but constant) name for each ethernet port on your system, rather than assigning them eth0, eth1, ... This means that if you have multiple ethernet ports you wont find that a different one is assigned the name eth0 on some boots, important for segregated networks etc. On the other hand it makes life a little bit more awkward if you just have one ethernet port.

On my system, I include the file etc/udev/rules.d/10-network.rules

```
# Set the name of the ethernet port to "net1"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="bc:5f:f4:ed:68:c6", NAME="net1"
```

to force a name to my ethernet port (where bc:5f... is the MAC address of my ethernet port, and "net1" is the name I want assigned to it). If I ever change the ethernet card, I just need to change the MAC address in this file, rather than try to find every reference to net1.

I cant help you with the second part of your question dhcp (I use dnsmasq)